# Removing/hiding controller name in the URL - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url

I've tried several ways to remove the controller name in my url but nothing works

my url are like : **www.mysite.com/controller/function** and I just want **www.mysite.com/function**

I've tried the routes but the controller name still remain in my url :/
Any trick to do that properly ?

Thanks!

Comment: consider resolving question by accepting/adding the answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you:

```
    $route['(:any)'] = "controller_name/$1";
```